# Alternative idiom to 'as it stands'

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

I am looking for an alternative idiom to 'as it stands'.

I have received a corpus of documents from a client which are unstructured in their delivery and file naming and I wish to reply along the lines of, 'as it stands the files we have received are not structured or named suitably'.

I am looking for an alternative to 'as it stands' as I feel it perhaps sounds a bit too confrontational, although I wish to convey the message they are unsuitable in their current structure.

Answer (score 3):

Ask yourself the question

> What does this clause add to what I am saying?

I think you will see that at most it is trying to soften the blow.  Delete it, and just go on to say what it is you require.  If soften it you must, you could try

> I’m afraid,...

Comment: Althougn this does not directly answer the question, it does address the issue and provides a great piece of advice in general. +1 for >What does this clause add to what I am saying?

Answer (score 2):

**at present** or **at the present time**  [TFD idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/present)

> currently

We are not accepting applications at present. Mr. Green is not in the office at the present time. And ... '**at present**, the files we have received are not structured or named suitably'.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the "as it stands" is not your problem, since nothing in your current circumstances is going to change to make the naming and structure more suitable. Try starting with "I understand that you've already put some [or "a lot of"] work into this, and I'm sorry to have to send it back, but ...", and explain what sort of structure you need, and why you need it that way.